# Finding results in a Enumerable object quickly

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, search

I am trying to write a utility to see if a user has logged in to windows since a date that I have stored in a database.

```
private void bwFindDates_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(context);
    u.SamAccountName = "WebLogin*";
    PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(u);
    var result = ps.FindAll();
    foreach (WebAccess.WebLoginUsersRow usr in webAccess.WebLoginUsers)
    {
        UserPrincipal b = (UserPrincipal)result.
            Single((a) => a.SamAccountName == usr.WEBUSER);
        if (b.LastLogon.HasValue)
        {
            if (b.LastLogon.Value < usr.MODIFYDATE)
                usr.LastLogin = "Never";
            else
                usr.LastLogin = b.LastLogon.Value.ToShortDateString();
        }
        else
        {
            usr.LastLogin = "Never";
        }
    }
}
```

However the performance is very slow. The user list I am pulling from has about 150 Windows users, so when I hit the line `UserPrincipal b = (UserPrincipal)result.Single((a) => a.SamAccountName == usr.CONVUSER);` it takes 10 to 15 seconds for it to complete per user (stepping through i can see it is doing the step `a.SamAccountName == usr.CONVUSE` is run for every person so the worst case is running O(n^2) times)

Any recommendations on ways to improve my efficiency?

Comment: I hate how SO somtimes likes to process tabs in a code section and sometimes not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>It's surprising that `Single()` should take quite so long on such a small list. I have to believe something else is going on here. The call to `ps.FindAll()` may be returning an object that does not cache it's results, and is forcing you to make an expensive call to some resource on each iteration within `Single()`.</s>

You may want to use a profiler to investigate where time is going when you hit that line. I would also suggest looking at the implementation of `FIndAll()` because it's returning something unusually expensive to iterate over.

So after reading your code a little more closely, it makes sense why `Single()` is so expensive. The `PrincipalSearcher` class uses the directory services store as the repository against which to search. **It does not cache these results**. That's what's affecting your performance.

You probably want to materialize the list using either `ToList()` or `ToDictionary()` so that accessing the principal information happens locally.

You could also avoid this kind of code entirely, and use the [`FindOne()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalsearcher.findone.aspx) method instead, which allows you to query directly for the principal you want.

But if you can't use that, then something like this should work better:

```
result.ToDictionary(u => u.SamAccountName)[usr.WEBUSER]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest:

```
var result = ps.FindAll().ToList();
```

Since [PrincipalSearchResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292002.aspx) doesn't cache like other things, this will bring you down near an O(n) performance level.

Answer (score 3):

```
var userMap = result.ToDictionary(u => u.SamAccountName);

foreach (WebAccess.WebLoginUsersRow usr in webAccess.WebLoginUsers)
{
    UserPrincipal b = userMap[usr.WEBUSER];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that I used `ToDictionary` because your use of `Single` implies that you expect exactly one match for every `WebLoginUsersRow`.  Adjust as necessary.

Comment: Thanks. about 15 secconds for the first entry and instantaneous for the rest.