# Set Local User Remote Desktop Services Environment and Session Settings

Tags: c#

I am working with local user accounts on a server and was wonder if there was a way possible to set the user's Remote Desktop Service start up environment when the account get's created.

Also if it was possible to set the users `sessions end disconnect session` and `idle session limit`. I am currently using `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` if there is way that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a look at this interface:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd919965(v=vs.85).aspx

the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409432/improving-performance-of-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement) post could help you on Remote Desktop startup path as well.